# Need advice on speeding up this MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

This is the query I am currently executing:

```
SELECT * FROM `datalog`
WHERE world_id IN (2) 
AND action IN (0,1,2,8,9,10,11,13,14,15)
AND x = -184.0 AND y = 98.0 AND z = 141.0
ORDER BY data_id DESC;
```

Unfortunately it is taking a long time and don't know why (5 seconds or more with 14 million entries in the database). I have an index on world_id and action (since there are only a max of 7 worlds and 20 actions). How else could i speed up searching?

EDIT - value of explain: SIMPLE datalog ALL NULL NULL NULL NULL 13510263 Using where; Using filesort

Comment: Proper indexes on on data_id, x, y, and z would probably help.

Comment: What is the output of `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM datalog...` (the rest of your query)?

Comment: ceejayoz: I wouldn't have thought indexes on them could be helpful, seeing as they can range from -100,000.0 to 100,000.0 (possibly more)

Comment: Explain: SIMPLE  datalog  ALL  NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL  13510263  Using where; Using filesort

Comment: How long does the query take if you do not do an ORDER BY?

Comment: The query is much faster without the ORDER BY! did not realise that would make such a difference. With the order by it took 54 seconds, without it took 4

Comment: Good. What exactly is data_id and why are you sorting by it?

Comment: It is the primary key and auto-incremented column for the table. I'm sorting by it because i want the results in reverse order. WOuld it be more efficient to reverse the order in my java program?

Comment: Yes, you could reverse the order in your client code. BTW, it is not considered best practice to rely upon an autoincrementing PK value as an indicator of recency; use a datetime value for that purpose. Many people do rely on it for that purpose however. But in the purist's world, the PK is nothing but a unique identifier for the tuple.

Comment: I do have other purposes for the pk value (in the program itself people can reference it etc) but I understand what you mean. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yes, but referencing it as a handle to reach the row is fine. It doesn't have any domain meaning there, but is simply the entity ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding indexes to x, y, and z.

You said that you thought this would not work since they can contain a large range of values.

As long as you are using a table type that supports `BTREE` indexes (this is the only index type that MyISAM and INNODB support), this should not be true.  If you are using a `HASH` index, that might be the case since it would need to index each value.  But with a `BTREE` index, MySQL is able to quickly sort for a specific value in the index.  This is why it is able to use `BTREE` indexes on queries with comparison operators as well (`<`, `>`, etc.)

You can see more here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-indexes.html

Comment: Thankyou, this ended up making it super fast (milliseconds for 15 million logs) - i already dropped it down to a few seconds by removing the group by thanks to Tim but indexing x,y,z was the cherry on top!

Answer (score 0):

You could try replacing your condition on action field by `AND action < 16`?

Comment: Action isn't less than 16 though, it can only be those specific values.

Comment: This wouldn't help since he said he has an index on action and he is looking for specific actions, not all actions less than 16.

Answer (score 0):

No idea if this would work, but have you tried reordering your conditions? x = -184.0 is likely to be faster than action in (...). If MySQL uses short circuiting, this could speed it up.

Comment: Nope, it was actually slower. If i remove the x,y,z stuff all together it is way faster than with the x,y,z

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @patapizza said, you should only use IN() if you basically have random things to look for so: `world_id = 2` and `action < 16`  will likely help.

You probably need indexes on the other columns you reference in the `WHERE` statement and probably on `data_id` as well. Like @AJ said though, post the output of `EXPLAIN` and it can be determined exactly why it's slow.

Comment: I can't do < 16 because i need to match specific values.

Comment: Output of explain: SIMPLE datalog ALL NULL NULL NULL NULL 13510263 Using where; Using filesort

Answer (score 0):

I would try a composite index: (actionid, worldid).

Comment: I already have a composite index on those two plus another column (player - not relevant in this situation)

Comment: What is the order of the columns in the composite index def?